# django+js: Display data in html using javascript

Tags: javascript, django

I have a function `get_data` in Django which returns `json.dumps(data)`. The view for the page which gets this file is:

```
def view_fn(request):
    data = get_data()
    return render(request, 'view.html', {'data': data})
```

I am experimenting with javascript and trying to get the `data` in html.

```
<script>
var json = '{{data}}';
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
alert(obj);
for (i in obj){
    document.write(obj[i]);
}
</script>
```

I am not able to display the json data in html file. Alert is also not working.

This happens when the data has a '\n' in it. How to write data to html using javascript in this case?

Comment: I know that all js has to be added in the base.html. Dunno if it will be rendered inside your template

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this:

```
<script>
var json = '{{data|safe}}';
obj = JSON.parse(json);
alert(obj);
</script>
```

If it doesn't help, then try `escapejs` tag. [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#escapejs)

That's all I can suggest without data example

Comment: In `View Page Source` I see the data, but js alert is not working.

Comment: When the data contains a '\n' it throws: 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON". Other than replacing the '\n', is there another way for this?

Comment: Maybe try another tag `var json = '{{data|safe|cut:"\n"}}';`

Comment: Also, please add the output of `console.log(json)` in case the above approach is not working.